# Algolia crawler not fetching google-codelabs-step label

Tags: web-crawler, algolia, google-codelab

**Problem**

I am using Algolia Crawler to fetch content from a webapp made with Codelabs. I do not understand why it is ignoring my request, and would like to know how to fetch  element.

**What I have done:**

Crawler cannot identify the  element, which I need to get hierarchy **lvl1**.

What I need to fetch is one of either elements:

```
google-codelab-step label="" 
h2 is-upgraded="" class="step-title"
```

But I have not being able to do so.
This is the html:

```
    <google-codelab-step label="" duration="" step="">
      <div class="">
        <div class="inner">
          <h2 is-upgraded="" class="step-title"> </h2>
    </google-codelab-step>
```

This is how my crawler:

```
    {
          indexName: "crawler_name",
          pathsToMatch: ["https://website.com/**"],
          recordExtractor: ({ helpers, $ }) => {
            const trainingLabel = $("#step-title").attr("h2");
            let returnLabel = trainingLabel ? trainingLabel : "";
            return helpers.docsearch({
              recordProps: {
                lvl1: returnLabel,
                content: "p, td, li",
                lvl0: {
                  selectors: ["#codelab-title > h1", "h1.title", "title"],
                  defaultValue: "default",
                },
                lvl2: "google-codelab-step h2",
                lvl3: "google-codelab-step h3",
                lvl4: "google-codelab-step h4",
                lvl5: "google-codelab-step h5, google-codelab-step td:first-child",
                lvl6: "google-codelab-step h6",
              },
            });
          },
        },
```

I am currently able to fetch: content, lvl0, lvl2 and lvl3. I tried to get lvl1 using the following possibilities, but non worked:

- const trainingLabel = $("#step-title").attr("h2");
- const trainingLabel = $("google-codelab-step").attr("label");
- const trainingLabel = $("google-codelab-step > #step-title").attr("h2");
- const trainingLabel = $("#step-title").attr("h2");
- const trainingLabel = $("step-title").attr("h2");
- const trainingLabel = $("step-title, h2").text();
- lvl1: "google-codelab-step > label",
- lvl1: "google-codelab-step > #step-title h2";

I highly appreciate it any help about how to fetch lvl1 item.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by using the basic template instead of using Docusaurus template, which comes with several information I did not understand.

This is how my action look like now:

```
{
  indexName: "crawler_name",
  pathsToMatch: ["https://url.com/**"],
  recordExtractor: ({ $, url }) => {
    const trainingLabel = $("google-codelab").attr("id");
    const trainingSubModules = $("google-codelab-step").attr("label");
    const titleHome = $("h1")
      .map((i, e) => $(e).text())
      .get();
    const moduleDescription = $("div.description")
      .map((i, e) => $(e).text())
      .get();
    const subtitle = $("h2")
      .map((i, e) => $(e).text())
      .get();
    const items = $("h3")
      .map((i, e) => $(e).text())
      .get();
    return [
      {
        titleHome: titleHome,
        trainingLabel: trainingLabel,
        trainingSubModules: trainingSubModules,
        moduleDescription: moduleDescription,
        subtitle: subtitle,
        items: items,
        objectID: url.href,
      },
    ];
  },
},
```

I had much more control by creating my own labels, instead of using the pre set hierarchy and helper.